# Load images from folder to exact coordinates

Tags: qt, qml

I have images, which names are the X and Y coordinates (i.e. "100_100.jpg", "200_100.jpg", "100_200.jpg", "200_200.jpg") in one folder ("img"). All images have the same width and height.

So the question is: How I can load the images automatically to coordinates that they have in their names without creating thousand lines of repeating code? (I will have much more than only those 4 images to load so the automation is a must)

Code:
main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 1000
    height: 800
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Tiled Photos")

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 20
        color: "#cdecf9"

        // THIS PART I WANT TO BE AUTOMATED:
        Image {
            id: img_100_100
            width: 100
            height: 100
            source: "img/100_100.png"
            asynchronous: true
            x: 100
            y: 100
        }

        Image {
            id: img_100_200
            width: 100
            height: 100
            source: "img/100_200.png"
            asynchronous: true
            x: 100
            y: 200
        }

        Image {
            id: img_200_100
            width: 100
            height: 100
            source: "img/200_100.png"
            asynchronous: true
            x: 200
            y: 100
        }

        Image {
            id: img_200_200
            width: 100
            height: 100
            source: "img/200_200.png"
            asynchronous: true
            x: 200
            y: 200
        }
        // END

    }
}
```

Comment: Deleting your question and reposting it is confusing. Do not do this anymore. Instead, edit [your original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65167922/qml-loading-images-to-specific-coordinates-from-folder) to meet the requirements of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't mention how the app knows what files there are. Maybe it's supposed to search a directory for these files, or maybe they're just a hardcoded list, etc. So let's assume you have a list of filenames that comes from...somewhere.

```
property var filenames: [
    "100_100.png",
    "100_200.png",
    "200_100.png",
    "200_200.png"
]
```

This is going to be the model for our `Repeater`. For readability, let's add a function that takes one of those filenames and extracts the x and y coordinates from it:

```
function getXY(filename) {
    // First chop off the extension by looking for the '.'
    var noExt = filename.split('.');

    // Then split the string up by the '_' character
    return noExt[0].split('_');
}
```

And finally, this is how we use it.

```
Repeater {
    model: filenames

    Image {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        asynchronous: true

        // Use the filename from the model
        source: "img/" + modelData

        // Store the result of our function call to get coordinates
        property var coordinates: getXY(modelData)
        x: coordinates[0]
        y: coordinates[1]
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am a fool. App only knows folder name in which it should search for images. Do you have idea how to modify it? In that folder will be only .jpg images with names as coordinates, so there is no need for advanced searching. Rest of your code work like a charm! :D

Comment: To get a list of files within a directory, use a [FolderListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html). It should hopefully be pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Thank you! You are a Master! :D